# whitespace in print statement - python v3.4

Tags: python, whitespace

I want to print"After tax, your total is: $8.74999125."
no whitespace after $ sign.

how could I do this in this statement?

```
print("After tax, your total is: $",total_price).
```

The output of this statement adds whitespace after $.

total price is type float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `total_price` to string, then use string concatenations:

```
print("After tax, your total is: $" + str(total_price))
```

Or use [strings formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
print("After tax, your total is: ${}".format(total_price))
```

Comment: Great! Thank you. I am wondering why the leading space is added at the output if string concatenation is not used.

Comment: The print function convert each separate argument to string and joins them by spaces. When using concatenation you pass only one argument that you design.

Comment: The space, which separates print arguments, can be changed using sep keyword parameter (see my answer below).

Answer (score 1):

I would use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

```
print("After tax, your total is: ${}".format(total_price))
```

Answer (score 1):

Third variant: it is also possible to change separator symbol (to empty string in current case):

```
print("After tax, your total is: $",total_price, sep='').
```